# Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document- Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-panel

After logged in to my Magento 2 admin, I got the below exception..

Can anyone help me to fix that issue?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 15

Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 15

#0 /home/xxxx/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()
#1 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(227): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl()
#2 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php(159): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin()
.......
```

Comment: can you please share your code in questions?

Comment: I am facing with this issue. can you tell me the way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Just add **title** attribute.

Go to [namespace]/[vendor]/etc/acl.xml

Ex. Mycustom/Custom/etc/acl.xml

then add **title.**

```
 <resource id="Mycustom_Custom::test" title="My Custom" >
     <resource id="Mycustom_Custom::test" title="My Custom" />
 </resource>
```

Answer (score 3):

To track down which module is causing the issue:

temp edit
`Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem`

at line 155 insert the validation routine:

```
if ($configMerger && !$configMerger->validate($this->_schemaFile, $errors)) {
                    $message = "Invalid Document \n";
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($message . implode("\n", $errors))
                    );
                }
```

and then set a breakpoint to trap the error.
then check the value of 'content' (the last ACL added)

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I simply added the key to the message to get the location of the faulty acl.xml like this $message = "Invalid Document location : ".$key."\n";  I do wish Magento would add proper file locations to their errors... Thank you for pointing me to the right code!

Comment: Let me add one more note: in my case the key (containing the location of the "faulty" acl) actually was the one after the actual faulty acl. So I added a $keyMinusOne variable to echo the location of the acl before the one throwing the error. That acl did not contain everything with the resource id="Magento_Backend::admin as it should have. Very happy with your answer @ProxiBlue, it saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

Check all of your custom and community modules code acl.xml file to check the missing title. Location of acl.xml is etc/acl.xml

Check whether a new resource id is created but title is missing for it.
Example of a correct acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Company_Base::config"
                                      title="Company Module Settings"
                                      sortOrder="9999" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Why does Magento not tell us which xml file is the error? I know they are doing standard PHP DOM validation, but this is very annoying. I think they need to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sandipan S is right but the important thing is how to find the wrong xml file. This process really tired me.

After many Google searches, I did not get any results. Finally, I applied the classic method.

---

The error I discovered was the use of `Magento_Adminhtml`.

`Magento_Backend` should have been used instead.

---

Here's what you need to do: You must narrow possible vendors and modules.

```
# Connect your server via SSH (with magento file owner user)
ssh {MagentoUser}@{YourServerNameOrIp}

# Go to your magento root (sample dir)
cd /var/www/html

# Move first custom vendor (or manny, if you want) avay to your user folder
# but be sure there is no folder exists named {Vendor} in your user folder
mv app/code/{Vendor1} /home/{MagentoUser}/{Vendor1}

# Test it
php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento setup:upgrade

# If fails again move second
mv app/code/{Vendor2} /home/{MagentoUser}/{Vendor2}

# And test it
php bin/magento cache:flush && php bin/magento setup:upgrade

# Finally if not fails move vendors back in one by one from first
mv /home/{MagentoUser}/{Vendor1} ./app/code/{Vendor1}
```

I hope it helps.